# How to use the GetStream.io API FrontEnd code to create a mobile app (based on a WebApp built with GetStream.io)?

Tags: mobile, frontend, getstream-io

Does GetStream.io allow building a frontend-only app? Can I use the frontend code (for UX/UI) of GetStream.io to create a ionic frontend mobile app? If it's not possible what should I do to build a frontend mobile app using GetStream.io (I'll connect the mobile app to the backend server of my web app using GetStream.io)?

If GetStream.io is frontend AND backend, how to do the "GetStream.io connected to a backend server that is connected to a mobile app"?

Comment: In fact the right question is "if I can use the Getstream.io Api front end code to create a mobile app based on a webapp built with Getstream.io?" So it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The front-end code you're referring to (https://github.com/GetStream/stream-js) is intended for reading streams only, using the read-only token. Exposing API keys and secrets in any front-end is not considered safe.

There's a separate JS library (https://github.com/GetStream/stream-analytics-js) intended for the analytics features (https://getstream.io/analytics/).

Please use back-end code for all other operations.